# Databind to gridview from backend c#, but show the fields only which is mentioned in BoundField of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using the linq to fetch from database and bind in the gridview using the below code:

**details.aspx.cs**

```
var mlo1 = (from nmo2 in nmo.PrimaCustDetails1s select nmo2).ToList();
custdet.DataSource = mlo1;
custdet.DataBind();
```

**details.aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="custdet" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

All the data from database will be shown.

I want to show only some fields from the table using `Boundfield`

```
<asp:GridView ID="custdet" runat="server">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="CustAccNo" HeaderText ="AccNo" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Customer Name" />

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I don't want other fields... Can someone advise me on how to do this?

Comment: autogeneratecolumns property should be set to false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set Gridview property `AutoGenerateColumns="false"`

```
   <asp:GridView ID="custdet" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CustAccNo" HeaderText ="AccNo" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Customer Name" />    
    </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` attribute to the `asp:GridView` element

Comment: thnak you i got it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set autogenerate property of gridview columns to false [Gridview Autogeneratecolumns Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx)

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="False" />
```